# How to generate PoJo class if we have the JSONobject and JSONarray in the API response?

Tags: android, json, pojo

```
{
    "CustId": "10705",
    "UserName": "3721",
    "Password": null,
    "AdminPassword": null,
    "CustName": "PB 65 V 3721",
    "CustType": "30",
    "CustKey": "980964ee-2abd-4352-9817-206d7ece8d04",
    "IsSubUser": true,
    "Announcement": "",
    "showIcons": "1111111111",
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "Status": true,
        "ErrorCode": null,
        "StackTrace": null,
        "Message": null,
        "Error": null
    }
}
```

Comment: check http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Use Google! There are hundreds of answers regarding this question out there! Try to search for Gson. Please, next time, before posting a question just make a small research on the web! If you want to become a developer one day, this is a crucial skill to have!

Comment: Try to use Jackson or GSON library to change JSON to java objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visit [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

1. Paste your JSON on Left Side.
2. Then Select type JSON
3. Annotation style: Gson
4. getter/setter
   click on preview/save Zip.

after your are done, you have to edit a bit to maintain Nested Classes.

Answer (score 0):

use json to pojo online tools. There is this one that i mostly use. Here is the [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Just post your response there and it will convert pojos for you. Then you can use gson to map json to your pojo.

I hope this will help you somehow.